# Image in bootstrap drop down causing overflow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am trying to input text and an image in a bootstrap navbar drop down. However, it is not being centered on the navbar and it also causes overflow gap when page is shrunk down. Here is a jsFiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/2r859fmx/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"></div>
        <div id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
                <span class="pull-left">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `div` under the `drop-down` menu for text and image. I have edited your code. May be this is the solve of your problem.

```
<a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
        <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                   <img class="circle img-responsive" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/spotmes3/photo.jpg">
              </div>

                   Brian
         </div>
</a>
```